# Chrome webdriver closes automatically

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use selenium for scraping and when I try to start the WebDriver it automatically closes. I've tried everything and it still doesn't work.

```
def launchBrowser():
    ch_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    ch_options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
    ch_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

    ch_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=ch_options)
    ch_driver.get(url)
    

launchBrowser()
```

I tried to implement some solutions I have seen but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: If you are running this code as a full script the driver will close because the script is finished and all of the destructors are being called. If you are trying to do development with the code to inspect the elements and write code from the automated browser it is probably recommended that you put this code into a jupyter notebook and continue, as the state of the driver is constant as the cells don't call the destructor for selenium when they have finished their task.